# How to Access Content Page buttons to another content page?

Tags: asp.net

I have button from another page and I want to set it to visible= false when it return after verification. Below are example codes.

```
 Dim btn As Button = Master.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("btnVerifyApproval")
        btn.Visible = False
```

How can I access that button of a content page to another content page?. Please Help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: @wintermute The scenario is like this in Page A bttnVerify is visible=true after that button has been clicked it will redirect to another page which is Page B (when vefication is validated then go back to PAge A and disable buttnVerfiy).

Comment: @wintermute I already solved thank you.